# Cancel all pendingIntent which using alarm service in android

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am new to android.I have set notification using PendingIntent like this

```
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("Msg", "Title");
        myIntent.putExtra("Msgdetail", "Description of notification");
        myIntent.putExtra("username","name");

       //for uniquely broadcast request

       Random random = new Random();
       int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
       PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, m, myIntent, 0);

      AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
      alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, c.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
```

Now i want to cancel all notification (PendingIntent) which i set using above code.I have searched on google and i got that i have to create same intent again but at that two things are missing id no and time. Although i have tired this but unluckily didn't work.

```
private void removenotifications() {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT, myIntent, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
}
```

any suggestion appreciated.Thank You.

Comment: These are alarms, not notifications. Notifications are what shows in the status bar, and has to be created best with Notification.Builder. Search for alarms instead of notifications.

Comment: i have done all that in NotificationService.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cancel an Intent, you must pass an intent to `alarmManager.cancel()` that **is equal** to the Intent you passed to `alarmManager.set()`. The intents must be equal as by the rules specified for [`Intent.filterEquals()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals(android.content.Intent)):

> Determine if two intents are the same for the purposes of intent
>   resolution (filtering). That is, if their action, data, type, class,
>   and categories are the same. This does not compare any extra data
>   included in the intents.

So, in your case, the problem is the random values you use when setting the alarms. You will have to store those random values somehow, and use them to create equal intents for cancelling.

Comment: At that how can i measure that this notification has been notified and this is not ???

Comment: Do you mean alarm, or notification? Again, those are two different things. About the alarm having happend, you know when your Intent is being invoked. The notification you have to create yourself anyways.

Comment: As per your answer i have to store that random no. but what about c.getTimeInMillis() in alarm.set() at the time of cancelling and how to store both that things. Thanks for you time @Ridcully

Comment: I suppose, `c` something you already store somewhere. If that "something" has an unique id, use that, instead of your random value. Otherwise, store the random value either together with the rest of `c` or e.g. in Preferences or something.

Comment: As for the milliseconds, you do not need them for cancelling the alarm, just the Intent. Think about it - when setting the alarm, you say : "Do Intent XY at 12:00", when cancelling it, you just say "Cancel Intent XY". No need for the time here, as Intent XY has to be unique by itself.